# Meteor universal link for ios not working

Tags: ios, meteor, deep-linking

My next app has to support universal linking for both iOS and android. For android everything is working but for iOS I just can't get it to work.
I have been using the following plugin: https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin. I have followed every step of the iOS web integration point.

In my "mobile-config.js" I'm using the following code: (I have changed my bundle ID and team ID in the pasted code for security reasons.)
```
    App.info({
      id: 'com.feu.project.sasmus',
      name: 'My website',
      version: 0.2,
    });

```
App.appendToConfig(`
  <widget id="com.feu.project.sasmus" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <universal-links>
      <ios-team-id value="8GFQSAHBBL" />
      <host scheme="https" name="website.eu.meteorapp.com" event="didLaunchAppFromLink"/>
    </universal-links>
  </widget>
`);
```

```

The "didLaunchAppFromLink" is living in my main.js file and is implemented in the following way: 
```

```
 componentWillMount() {
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
      universalLinks.subscribe('didLaunchAppFromLink', function(eventData){
        browserHistory.replace(eventData.url);
      });
    }
  }
```

```
 (this is working for android so I assume this will also work for iOS?)

I also had to create an "apple-app-site-association" file and place this into my "public" folder. I did this in the following way: 
```

```
{
  "activitycontinuation": {
    "apps": [
      "8GFQSAHBBL.com.feu.project.sasmus"
    ]
  },
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "8GFQSAHBBL.com.feu.project.sasmus",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
This file is downloadable like apple wants it via the following link: https://website.eu.meteorapp.com/apple-app-site-association (this won't work here because I changed the website name for security reasons)

So far as I know I completed all the tasks and I don't see where I did wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This plugin hasn't been updated for a while. I'd suggest looking into [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links as an alternative